Vercel middleware crash - __dirname is not defined
Has anybody ever experienced this issue while deploying a nextjs app on vercel?
The deployment is successful but causes this runtime error
ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at (node_modules/next/dist/compiled/ua-parser-js/ua-parser.js:1:17315)
    at (node_modules/next/dist/compiled/ua-parser-js/ua-parser.js:1:17444)
    at (node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/user-agent.js:27:59)
    at (node_modules/next/server.js:8:0)
    at (src/middleware.js:37:29)
    at (middleware:middleware.js:1:17)

Context

I'm not using __dirname anywhere in my app or middleware, it seems to be internally used by nextjs.
This error is not thrown in localhost.

My matcher looks like this
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/signin",
    "/signup",
    "/",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/onboarding/:path*",
    "/settings/:path*",
    "/chat/:path*",
    "/notes/:path*",
    "/chatbot/:path*",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/notifications/:path*",
    "/meeting/:path*",
    "/stripe/:path*",
  ],
};

I'm not able to figure out what is causing this crash. I'll be very grateful if someone can help me fix this. Thanks!

You can try to use process.cwd()

Thats because Vercel Edge runtime is built on top of the V8 engine and not on node.js

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/21009#issuecomment-1926447642
check this out if you're using supabase
